# loopj - Socket Timeout - response body is null, calling onFailure(Throwable, JSONObject)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, socketexception, loopj

I seem to be getting intermittent **SocketTimeout** exceptions when either calling GET or POST using the **loopj** library for **Android**.

However this error only seems to be an issue on certain versions of android. That being said I've removed the SSL certificate setup I had on my api class and I am now just calling standard http get/post.

Errors that are being thrown are intermittently:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

or

> ```
> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x6118a8: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
> ```

I have checked the error log on apache and i am getting:

> client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed
>   too while sending request to upstream

I am not sure if this is an issue at all?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import android.util.Log;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class Api {
    private static String api_url = "http://myurl.co.uk/api";
    private static VenueManager venueManager;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://myurl.co.uk/api";
    private static boolean success = false;
    private static AsyncHttpClient client = null;
    public static final String api_key = "API_KEY";
    public static final String api_secret = "API_SECRET";
    static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 20 * 1000;

//  public static AsyncHttpClient get_client()
//  {
//      if(client != null)
//      {
//          return client;
//      }
//      else
//      {
//          client = new AsyncHttpClient();
//          try 
//          {
//              KeyStore trustStore = //KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
//              trustStore.load(null, null);
//              SocketFactory sf = new SocketFactory(trustStore);
//              //sf.setHostnameVerifier(SocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
//              client.setSSLSocketFactory(sf);
//              client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
//          }
//          catch (Exception e) 
//          { 
//              Log.v("API", e.toString());
//          }
//          
//          return client;
//      }
//  }

    public static String get_api_url()
    {
        return api_url;
    }

    public static String search_venues(double lat, double lng)
    {
        return get_api_url() + "/venues?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng + "&radius=1.0";
    }

    public static String post_review()
    {
        return get_api_url() + "/review";
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
         return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
    }

    public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(5, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(5, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static String sha1(String s) {
        MessageDigest digest = null;
        try 
        {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        digest.reset();
        byte[] data = digest.digest(s.getBytes());
        return String.format("%0" + (data.length*2) + "X", new BigInteger(1, data));
    }
}
```

Above is my API class. Below is a method I call within an activity

```
public void check_survey()
    {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("email", sharedPreferences.getString("email", null));
        params.put("password", sharedPreferences.getString("password", null));
        params.put("api_key", Api.api_key);

        Api.get("/survey", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loading.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                loading.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                try
                {
                    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject meta = result.getJSONObject("meta");

                    if(meta.getBoolean("success"))
                    {     
                        if(result.getString("response").equals("true"))
                        {
                            // do something
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // display errors
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.v("Error", e.toString());
                }
                loading.dismiss();
            }
        });
}
```

I'm really at a loose end as to why this is happening.

Comment: were you able to get this solved??

Comment: I'm not quite sure because later on I had some other problems which turned out to be the server SSL config. So I wouldn't like to say it was loopj per say.